# Dynamically load second bootstrap selectpicker based on user input of first selectpicker in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to load data from the database to the second selectpicker based on the input id of the first selectpicker. In the database id of the first selectpicker is the foreign key of the second selectpicker.

View file

> 1st selectpicker

```
<select name="depot_select" id="depot_select" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  value="<?php echo set_value('depot_select');?>">
                            <option value="">No Depot Selected</option>
                            <?php echo $depots['depot'] ?>
</select>
```

> 2nd selectpicker

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="route_select" id="route_select" value="<?php echo set_value('route_select');?>">
                            <option value="">No Route Selected</option>
                            <?php echo $routes['route']?>
</select>
```

Ajax

```
function fetchDepot(){

        $.ajax({
                    type    :'POST',
                    url     : '<?php echo base_url('transporter_dashboard/bus/get_depots'); ?>',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data)
                    {
                         $('#depot_select').empty();               
                         var example =  $('#depot_select').selectpicker('val', data['data']);
                         console.log("depot_select"  + example);

                          if(!$.isEmptyObject(data))
                          {

                             $.each(data, function(i,o)
                            {
                                 var depot = $('#depot_select').append('<option value="'+ o['dpt_id'] +'">'+o['dpt_name'] +' </option>');


                            });


                          }
                       $('#depot_select').selectpicker('refresh');
                       fetchRoute();
                        
                    },
                    error: function()
                    {
                        alert('error occour..........!');
                    }
            });


    }


    function fetchRoute()
      { 

        $.ajax(
        {   
            type    :'POST',
            url     :'<?php echo base_url('transporter_dashboard/bus/get_routes'); ?>',
            data    : { dpt_id : $('#depot_select option:selected').val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(data)
            {


                $('#route_select').empty();
                 $('#route_select').selectpicker('val', data['data']);

                if(!$.isEmptyObject(data))
                {

                    $.each(data, function(i,o)
                    {
                        var route = $('#route_select').append('<option value="'+ o['rot_id'] +'">'+ o['rot_name'] +'</option>');

        

                    });                      

                }
                
                $('#route_select').selectpicker('refresh');

            },
             error: function(data){

                alert('error occour..........!');

            }

        });
    }
```

Controller

```
function get_depots()
{

    echo json_encode($this->bus_model->get_depots());

}

function get_routes()
{
    if ($this->input->post('dpt_id')) 
        {
            echo json_encode($this->bus_model->get_routes($this->input->post('dpt_id')));
        }


}
```

Model

```
function get_depots()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $data = $this->db->get('depots')->result_array();
        return $data;
    }

function get_routes($id)
{
     $data = array();
        
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('dpt_id',$id);
        $data = $this->db->get('routes')->result_array();

        return $data;

}
```

[image: depot table]
[image: routes table]

According to the above code, only the id of the first option goes to the backend every time despite what option is selected. Then database load only those data which belongs to the id of the first option.

[image: request send to the backend]

Comment: Did you try like this `$('#depot_select').val()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer to this question. We need to call `fetchRoute()` function inside of the `$( document ).ready()`